# How to strip out all html tags from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/ZTuDJ/23/) I have:

I want to make sure the user doesn't put any html tags in the "Add Responsibilities" field. So for example, if the user writes this:

```
<div>Test</div>
```

Then it would put this into the responsibility field:

```
Test
```

I think it's something to do with this command but I can't get it working within my code:

```
$("#resp_input").html( $("#resp_input").text() );
```

Comment: no, that has nothing to do with the html() command!!!

Comment: Don't. Instead, encode HTML entities when you later *output* the string.

Comment: check out the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript?rq=1

Comment: You seem to be looking for [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project)

Comment: @meagar Are you saying I shouldn't try to strip it out with javascript and process it later with my PHP to strip out the tags?

Comment: @Jimmy No, I'm saying you shouldn't make any attempt to strip out the tags. If a user enters their name as `<b>meagar</b>`, you should render their name as `&lt;b&gt;meagar&lt;/b&gt;`, which is completely safe. The user is entering what they *meant* to enter, you should preserve their content exactly as they give it to you, and render back to them exactly as it looked when they typed it. Doing lossy things like trying to strip "special" characters out of user input is wrong-headed, and adds literally zero security. **100%** of security (where tag-injection is concerned) happens on output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this code:

```
$('#responsibilities').text($("<div>" + eachline + "</div>").text() );
```

see [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTuDJ/28/)

Comment: Can you please explain this line? It works but i dont understand it. I dont really understand why the div is there

Comment: it is converting any text inserted to DIV, and then reads the text inside